# Why I must put "AS" clause at the end of subquery.?

Tags: sql, subquery

I saw this thread:

```
SELECT
    MAX(totalcontracts) AS highest_total   
FROM ( SELECT 
        SuperVisor                               
        ,COUNT(ContractNo) AS totalcontracts       
       FROM Contract                                    
       GROUP BY SuperVisor                              
    ) AS t
```

If I delete "as t" line that return me an error. but when I put it back that work fine.
This is temporarly so why do I required to put a name to that subtable?Any sense in that? 
Thank you.

Comment: Because any nested subquery needs an alias in order to get data from it.

Comment: What database system are you using? In SQL Server you need to tell the system the name of the subquery. You don't necessarily need to have the 'AS', it can just be ') t' but it needs to be named.

Comment: That `AS table-alias` part is optional according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard. However, some products require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard SQL a derived table (a subquery you select data from) needs a name:

```
FROM (<subquery>) [AS] <name>`
```

(Some DBMS, however, are not compliant with the standard. In Oracle for instance it is not mandatory to give a derived table an alias, but the optional `AS` is forbidden when you specify one. Other DBMS on the other hand may require the `AS` although the SQL standard specifies it as optional.)

Answer (score 0):

As @jarlh mentioned, if you're using some database systems, in order to use the result from any nested subquery you need to give that result-set a name (or alias), which is why you need to put a name / letter / character after you close the paranthesis.

The `AS` keyword is not mandatory, but the name is.

Comment: If using some dbms products... (Optional according to the SQL standard.)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a real logic necessity here.
Oracle for instance does not force it

```
select * from (select * from dual);
```

Nor SQLite

```
select * from (select 1)
```

Comment: Still no problem unless a column is ambiguous. Anyway ,I didn't say it is never needed , however it is definitly not always needed, as in the OP example.